# mysql 2 columns as 1 (not merged!)

Tags: php, mysql

Sounds simple but i cant work out if it is possible or not...
As it sounds simple and is only a very small query it seems logical to do it in SQL rather than have to write php/etc to do this.

i have 2 columns that i want returning in 1 column but not merged and not if 1 of them in null, etc.

i have this (very basic)

```
SELECT DISTINCT PropertyDistrict as Area, PropertyTown as Area 
FROM tProperty
```

However this gives me 2 columns (both called area, with the results side by side), and ideally i want them as 1 column

COALESCE() and CONCAT() just merge them so this does not give me what i want.
basically i would like the results as though they were all in the same column ( a row per result).

Any ideas if this is possible?

Update:
the above results in :

```
# Area, Area
'Staffordshire', 'Stoke-on-Trent'
NULL, 'Blakesley'
NULL, 'Wick'
```

what i want is :

```
# Area
'Staffordshire'
'Stoke-on-Trent'
'Blakesley'
'Wick'
```

simply a list of all areas
thanks!

Comment: Show us your desired output along with sample input data.

Comment: Do you just want to select them this way or create a new column with this new data in

Comment: this is what i get # Area, Area
'Staffordshire', 'Stoke-on-Trent'
NULL, 'Blakesley'
NULL, 'Wick'
NULL, ''
NULL, 'Penzance'
NULL, 'Straiton'
NULL, 'Paignton'
NULL, 'Taunton'
NULL, 'Plymouth'
NULL, 'Rye'
NULL, 'York'
NULL, 'Penderyn'
NULL, 'Ayr'
NULL, 'Edinburgh'
NULL, 'Sturminster Newton'
NULL, 'Weston on the Green'
What i want is #Area 
'Staffordshire'
'Stoke-on-Trent'
'Blakesley'
'Wick'

Comment: how about using `union`? `select PropertyDistrict` first then `union` `select PropertyTown` ?

Comment: it is not to create a new column, simply want a list of all areas

Comment: maybe UNION could be used, just seems over complicated for such a simple query, i was wondering if there was a simpler way that would be faster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT PropertyDistrict as Area 
FROM tProperty 
WHERE PropertyDistrict IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT PropertyTown as Area 
FROM tProperty
WHERE PropertyTown IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: hehe we must have been typing at the same time. you are of course right. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks All

Union works fine with:

```
SELECT DISTINCT PropertyTown Area
FROM tProperty 
WHERE PropertyTown != ''
   UNION
SELECT DISTINCT PropertyDistrict Area
FROM tProperty 
WHERE PropertyDistrict != ''
Order By Area ASC
```

And seem plenty fast enough
thanks!